# Не добавляется длинная строка в кукис

Tags: javascript

У меня есть массив следующего типа:

```
var survey = [
    {question_id: "survey_id_1", question: "вава", answer: "1", date_first: null, date_second: null},
    {question_id: "survey_id_2", question: "авав", answer: "2", date_first: null, date_second: null},
    {question_id: "survey_id_3", question: "йцйц", answer: "3", date_first: null, date_second: null},
    {question_id: "survey_id_4", question: "уцуц", answer: "4", date_first: null, date_second: null},
    {question_id: "survey_id_1", question: "вава", answer: "1", date_first: null, date_second: null},
    {question_id: "survey_id_2", question: "авав", answer: "2", date_first: null, date_second: null},
    {question_id: "survey_id_3", question: "йцйц", answer: "3", date_first: null, date_second: null},
    {question_id: "survey_id_4", question: "уцуц", answer: "4", date_first: null, date_second: null},
    {question_id: "survey_id_1", question: "вава", answer: "1", date_first: null, date_second: null},
    {question_id: "survey_id_2", question: "авав", answer: "2", date_first: null, date_second: null},
    {question_id: "survey_id_3", question: "йцйц", answer: "3", date_first: null, date_second: null},
    {question_id: "survey_id_4", question: "уцуц", answer: "4", date_first: null, date_second: null},
    {question_id: "survey_id_1", question: "вава", answer: "1", date_first: null, date_second: null},
    {question_id: "survey_id_2", question: "авав", answer: "2", date_first: null, date_second: null},
    {question_id: "survey_id_3", question: "йцйц", answer: "3", date_first: null, date_second: null},
    {question_id: "survey_id_4", question: "уцуц", answer: "4", date_first: null, date_second: null},
    {question_id: "survey_id_1", question: "вава", answer: "1", date_first: null, date_second: null},
    {question_id: "survey_id_2", question: "авав", answer: "2", date_first: null, date_second: null},
    {question_id: "survey_id_3", question: "йцйц", answer: "3", date_first: null, date_second: null},
    {question_id: "survey_id_4", question: "уцуц", answer: "4", date_first: null, date_second: null},
    // Если добавлять элементы выше, то они отлично заносятся в кукис. Но любые элементы далее просто 
    // не заносятся, если их больше 20. Уменьшая количество до 20 все ок. Никаких ручных ограничений я не ставил!
    {question_id: "survey_id_1", question: "вава", answer: "1", date_first: null, date_second: null},
    {question_id: "survey_id_2", question: "авав", answer: "2", date_first: null, date_second: null},
    {question_id: "survey_id_3", question: "йцйц", answer: "3", date_first: null, date_second: null},
    {question_id: "survey_id_4", question: "уцуц", answer: "4", date_first: null, date_second: null},
    ]
```

Я перевожу его в строку JSON и хочу добавить её в кукис.

```
// Эта функция заменяет {}, которые не позволительны в JSON на []
// и располагает ключ значение ключ значение по их порядку

function survey_to_arrays(obj) {
    // transforms
    // [ {"x" : "y", "c" : "z"} ]
    // to
    // [ ["x", "y", "c", "z"] ]
    var d, val
    var result = []
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        d = obj[i]
        result.push([])
        for (var key in d) {
            val = d[key]
            result[result.length-1].push(encodeURIComponent((key))
            result[result.length-1].push(encodeURIComponent((val))
        }
    }
    return encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(result))
}

// заношу в кууис
document.cookie = "answers=" + survey_to_arrays(survey)
```

Но больше 20 элементов он не хочет заносить в кукис \ переводить. Я знаю, что у кукис нет ограничений по длине, и, наверное, ошибка в другом. (Если убирать мою функциию и просто

```
 document.cookie = "answers=" + survey_to_arrays(survey)
```

То ничего не заносится.

Что не так и как мне занести этот массив в кукис?

**Правка 1**

Функция нормально возвращает строку, которая правильно кодирована для передачи в кукис. Значит дело все-таки в присваивании на строке `document.cookie = ...`

Comment: сохраните в localstorage? там лимит 10МБ

Comment: @IgorZinchenko сохраняю в кукис и даже если разделить на части то сервер не позволяет сохранять такой обьем. Поэтому, наверное, буду сохранять в БД на JS, а не на php как планировал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Интернет напротив, говорит, что длина куки ограничена (минимальный размер 4096 байт, максимальный уже зависит от браузера):

> Google Chrome - 4096 байт;
> Internet Explorer - 5117 байт;
> Firefox - 4097 байт

источник https://www.lifewire.com/cookie-size-limit-3466810

Comment: Оу. Насколько я понял - это для одной пары ключ-значение таковые ограничения, а не для всех кукис на сайте?

Comment: @WhoAmI, для каждой пары ключ-значение